# PHP/SQL - Insert only existing columns

Tags: php, sql

I am going to update a database based on the contents of an XML file submitted by a 3rd party.

The thing is the structure of the XML file will vary and also have values of nodes that don't go into the database.

Because the structure a varies I will have to check the name of a node and direct the child data to the right table based on that name. However I would need to attempt to insert all the child node values into the database because I can't predict what child nodes will be present.

So in one case I may get:

```
<xyz>
 <abc>
 <test>test</test>
</abc>
</xyz>
```

Another time it may be:

```
<xyz>
 <pqr>
 <test>test</test>
 <name>test</name>
</pqr>
</xyz>
```

So I can set the table name to abc or pqr easily enough, but if pqr does not have the column 'test' then I can't loop through  adding values to the SQL INSERT.

Ideally I would be able to write something in SQL that would ignore attempts to add values to columns that don't exist.

Comment: Use MySQL's [Show Columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html) command to see what you can store before importing and use PHP to check if the field can be imported. You could store each row in a array or class and do the save after each row is read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL's Show Columns command as suggested by AeroX works.